# Disable/change pivot animations on UWP

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, win-universal-app, slide

A pivot item's "slide-in-from-the-side" animation is played not only when swiping, but also when clicking the pivot item's header with a mouse on a desktop.

How can i disable this animation? Either completely, or only for explicit clicks/taps on the header.

Comment: Please check the reply of your same thread on MSDN firstly.

Comment: so far, nothing helpful has been replied there.

Comment: If we go look at a [Pivot default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx) we see the `ItemsPresenter` with a `TransformGroup` towards the bottom. Those would be your culprits.

Comment: @ChrisW. i agree, but how do i modify them? If i remove them the pivot breaks down, and i cannot find any documentation on what a `ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform` or a `ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform` is supposed to be or do.

Comment: @Benni : Any chance you resolved this issue?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not. My thread on MSDN received no substantial responses, they apparently did not even read my question correctly.

Comment: Have you tried the new TabView Control? which is somewhat similar to pivot but without any animation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tabview

Answer (score 1):

I think the one you are looking for is the new control `TabView` solves this issue. Please have a look. It supports from the min version **16299**.

Added a image from Microsoft Docs for reference.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tabview